# Keep materialize tab open after page reload

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, materialize

I want keep materialize tab open after page reload and send link to users of tab e.g. http://www.example.com/samplepage#tab

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="userdashboard-tabs">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#Dashboard" role="tab" aria-controls="Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Orders" role="tab" aria-controls="Orders">My Orders</a> </li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Products" role="tab" aria-controls="Products">My Products</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Sells" role="tab" aria-controls="Sells">My Sells</a>
 </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Account" role="tab" aria-controls="Account">My Account</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

here is javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#userdashboard-tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tabs();
  });

  // store the currently selected tab in the hash value
  $("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("click", function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    console.log(id + "dijdljsodfj");
    window.location.hash = id;
  });

  // on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  console.log(hash +"hash");
  $('#userdashboard-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').click();

})
```

page reload gives this error:

```
jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
```

clicking tab gives this error:

```
materialize.js:4019 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kind of late, but this worked for me:

in every tab anchor I have put the data-toggle attribute:

```
<a data-toggle="tab"
```

Then I used the tabs configuration like this:

```
// Init tabs
$(".tabs").tabs();

// Show active tab on reload
if (location.hash !== '') {
  $('.tabs').tabs('select', location.hash);
}

// Remember the hash in the URL without jumping
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(e) {
  if (history.replaceState) {
    history.replaceState(null, null, '#' + $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1));
  } else {
    location.hash = '#' + $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
  }

  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```